# how to draw skewed (unbalanced) tree with tikz-qtree?

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, tikz-qtree

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\Tree  [.Appl [.DP ] [.V [.DP ] [.v ] ]]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

is giving me the above picture:  [image]

But, what I really want is left skewed DP node  without the v node. [image]I want to eliminate the pixelated part.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. For future, it's better to post complete minimal documents (like the code in my answer) rather than just code fragments.  This makes sure that the package you are loading is correct and people will be able to help you more easily.  See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw explicit edges using the `\edge` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}

\Tree  [.Appl [.DP ] [.V  DP \edge[draw=none]; {\phantom{XP}} ]]

\end{document}
```

I've used a `\phantom{XP}` node here instead of just `{}` so that the left branch angle is nicer.

[image: output of code]